# Sencha touch Animation's after handler not taking a function

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am using Sencha touch 2.0.1.1.
In the view I am doing some animation in dragend function of a container and on this animation end I want to perform some more things, but the `after` handler is not taking function as handler. Here is the code

```
                Ext.Animator.run({
                    element: dataview.element,
                    duration: 500,
                    autoClear : true,
                    easing: 'ease-in',
                    preserveEndState: true,
                    to: {
                        height: to_h
                    },
                    from: {
                        height: dataview.element.getHeight()
                    },
                    after: function() {
                        console.log ("After run");
                    }     
                });
```

This is the error I get:

```
Uncaught Error: [ERROR][Ext.fx.animation.Abstract#applyAfter] Invalid config, must be a valid config object Console.js:17
```

but this somehow works if I do like this:

```
                Ext.Animator.run({
                    element: dataview.element,
                    duration: 500,
                    autoClear : true,
                    easing: 'ease-in',
                    preserveEndState: true,
                    to: {
                        height: to_h
                    },
                    from: {
                        height: dataview.element.getHeight()
                    },
                    after: {
                        fn : console.log (this)
                    }
                });
```

Since I want to do bunch of things apart from just console.log so can someone suggest me right way to use this handler to execute a function which is written in-place or in the view?

Answer (score 0):

Try 'onEnd:'  instead of 'after:'